# How do I enable functions in my DevHub org?

Tags: salesforcedx, feature-activation, salesforce-functions

I have enabled DevHub in my developer edition org.

[image]

But I am still not able to enable "Salesforce Functions".

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: As of now, it's available to try on local computer. If  you're interested to begin with, you can try the same. You need SFDX updated unified CLI, docker installed, SFDX 7.121+.  You can either follow functions recipies on github or just create a function CLI automatically add few files as per the technology.

Comment: Yeah locally it does work with docker but the only issue is we cannot call it from Apex as of now.

Comment: yes as of now same is pending. As of now, untill dev hub gets that feature we can't enable functions in scratch org and without that we can't invoke same from apex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While Salesforce functions are now GA, they are not available for use inside of a developer edition Salesforce org.

There was a [blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/10/salesforce-functions-is-generally-available) released today announcing the GA that has much more information.

Currently, if you would like to get access to functions you have two options:

1. In the coming weeks there will be a sign up released to get a trial org, as outlined in the blog.
2. Speak to your companies account team to have functions purchased and activated - they will be able to give you all of the details as we don't have them to share.

For the time being you can access the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/index.html) and [trailhead quick look](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce-functions-quick-look?trail_id=discover-salesforce-functions).

Comment: The strange part is this is not even available in our production org, or lower orgs. Does this mean my company has to buy this feature from salesforce. I thought this feature was free.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Trailhead as well.

Comment: Is it also not available in Trailhead orgs? I'm going through the "Quick Start: Explore the Functions Recipes Sample App" on Trailhead but my org doesn't have the Enable option in Setup/Functions.

Comment: @Bahman.A no, they aren't enabled on Trailhead Playground orgs.

Comment: You can use Functions and connect to a DevHub by using the local development experience, you can take a look at [Getting Started with Salesforce Functions Locally. No license required!](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/11/getting-started-with-salesforce-functions-locally-no-license-required)